# Storing and deleting placemarks

Tags: google-apps, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

I am trying to store placemarks in a global array but not sure what I'm actually trying to store.  I want to be able to remove the placemark at a later time.  Do I just need to store the lat and lng or do I need to store some kind of placemark obj in the array.  I've tried to look at the google docs but they are I think written in greek.  Could someone point me in the right direction??

Inside a for loop on the global array PASSENGERS we have the following code:

```
// prepare placemark
var placemark = earth.createPlacemark("");
placemark.setName(PASSENGERS[i].name + " to " + PASSENGERS[i].house);

// prepare icon
var icon = earth.createIcon("");
icon.setHref(url + "/img/" + PASSENGERS[i].username + ".jpg");

// prepare style
var style = earth.createStyle("");
style.getIconStyle().setIcon(icon);
style.getIconStyle().setScale(4.0);

// prepare stylemap
var styleMap = earth.createStyleMap("");
styleMap.setNormalStyle(style);
styleMap.setHighlightStyle(style);

// associate stylemap with placemark
placemark.setStyleSelector(styleMap);

// prepare point
var point = earth.createPoint("");
point.setAltitudeMode(earth.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND);
point.setLatitude(building.lat);
point.setLongitude(building.lng);
point.setAltitude(0.0);


// associate placemark with point
placemark.setGeometry(point);
```

I thought I could print out placemark with:

```
for (var prop in placemark) 
{
  console.log(prop + " = " + placemark[prop]);
}
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to take some time and try to understand the docs.

See https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/placemarks?csw=1

Once you add placemarks to the the plugin they are in memory inside the plugin and there is no need to store them in another array.

You can assign the placemark an id.

```
// to add
var placemark= ge.createPlacemark('your_id_here');
ge.getFeatures().appendChild(placemark);

// to remove
var myPlacemark= ge.getElementById('your_id_here');
ge.getFeatures().removeChild(myPlacemark);
```